# BigQuery - Select event param value based on another event param

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

[image]In my app, I send an event 'content_view' to Firebase analytics whenever a user opens one a certain view. This event has two event parameters associated with it: content_type and title. content_type is always either 'audio', 'story', 'video', or 'image' and then title is self-explanatory.

That data then goes into Big Query.

In Big Query, I want to list out the top 5 videos with the most views by title and number of events. I can get the top 5 events by title, but I can't figure out how to only do that only for events where content_type = 'video'.

Is there a way to build a query that returns something like this?

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+
|  Title  | Total Views | Content Type |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| Video 1 |        1000 | video        |
| Video 2 |         900 | video        |
| Video 3 |         800 | video        |
| Video 4 |         700 | video        |
| Video 5 |         600 | video        |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE content_type = 'video'` ???

Comment: can you provide schema of your table?

Comment: I added the schema. The problem is firebase sends all of these event parameters inside the event_params field. So content_type and title are both keys inside event_params. I'm pretty sure I need to do some type of UNNEST. Then I'm lost after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and is based on (*and tested for*) schema you provided

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  (
    SELECT MAX(IF(key = 'title', value.string_value, NULL)) title
    FROM UNNEST(event_params) param 
    WHERE (key = 'content_type' AND value.string_value = 'video')
    OR key = 'title'
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
  ) Title,
  COUNT(1) TotalViews
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY Title
HAVING NOT title IS NULL
ORDER BY TotalViews DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I was looking for. If possible, can you explain what "HAVING COUNT(1) = 2" is doing?

Comment: sure, will get back shortly and add some explanations :o)

Comment: @user3321348 - sorry, got this action item lost and only now recall that I owe you some explanation - will try to make it by tomorrow end of the day - got too busy today

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(1) = 2` makes sure that only those rows selected which have both (2) conditions `contenttype=video and there is an entry with key=type. You can remove this clause and see how result will be changed :o)

Answer (score 0):

Modify to suit your column names and the name of your project/dataset/table name:

```
SELECT title, total_views, content_type
FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`
WHERE content_type = 'video'
```

Comment: I edited the question with the schema. Firebase is sending these events and content_type and title are part of the event_param field which is some type of array I guess.